# How to convert API timestamp into python datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, rfc3339

I am getting the following string from an API call:

```
s = '2014-12-11T20:46:12Z'
```

How would I then convert this into a python object? Is there an easy way, or should I be splitting up the string, for example:

```
year = s.split('-')[0]
month = s.split('-')[1]
day = s.split('-')[2]
time = s.split('T')[1]
...etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) function:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s = '2014-12-11T20:46:12Z'
>>> datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 11, 20, 46, 12)
>>>
```

For a complete list of the available format codes, see [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Using `datetime` should do it, recently I found [arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) is also a good library to deal with dates.

```
import arrow
s = '2014-12-11T20:46:12Z'
your_date = arrow.get(s)
print(t.year)  # 2014
print(t.hour)  # 20
```

Comment: I wish I knew about Arrow like 4 years ago. That probably just saved me 30 minutes of fiddling with a weird time format.